# Why is 讲 where it is in 他英语讲得很好?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, adverbs

I was doing a sentence rearranging exercise and came across this:

> 他英语讲得很好。

Could someone explain the structure of this sentence?  I feel like it would be more properly written as:

> 他会说英语说得很好。

I was confused thinking that 英语 is the object of 讲 and so then would go after the verb. Could I say "他讲英语。"? Maybe "他讲英语讲得很好。"? And the explanation is that the first 讲 is just left out?

Why can't it be "他讲得很好英语。"? Is it just weird to have the adverbial phrase before the language being spoken?

Comment: 他英语讲得很好  with fronted object (英语) and complement of degree (程度补语）得很好 fronting object has the advantage that the verb need not be repeated, if object follows verb , then verb 讲 must be repeated as in 他讲英语讲得很好

Comment: Aha! Ok, I think that makes sense. So then I could say "我饭做很快了。" for I quickly cooked a meal? Is "我做饭了做很快。" grammatically correct also?  I assume there are probably instances where putting the object in front of the verb is ok and other instances when it is not ok. Is there a Chinese term for this "fronted object"? 谢谢您！

Comment: fronted object 前置宾语（外国人实用汉语语法）从结构上看，谓语前边或后边常带状语或补语 structually,the predicate is usually preceded by an adverbial adjunct or followed by a complement 例如：我这些文章能看懂。我上海去过，南京也去过。他们那个展览会已经参观了。他英语，汉语说得很好。Alternative suggestions: 我饭做得很快（了）。我做饭了做得很快。

Comment: Thank you very much! I did indeed leave out the "得" accidentally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe "他讲英语讲得很好。"? And the explanation is that the first 讲 is just left out?

Exactly this.

The grammatical rule here is pretty simple, but sometimes overlooked: 
with **complements of grade** (得 + verbal phrase) the **main verb is doubled**, in order to keep the strong bound between verb + object and between verb + grade particle, so your example would be actually written:

> 他**讲**英语**讲**得很好

Then, the first occurrence of the main verb (the one before the object) **can be omitted**, so you end up with:

> 他 (subject) 
>   <s>讲 (main verb)</s> 
>   英语 (object) 
>   讲 (verb doubled) 
>   得 (grade particle) 
>   很好 (verbal phrase)

Answer (score 0):

Let's use x-bar theory to examine the grammar of this sentence:

`S---他英语讲得很好
 |
 |--Noun Phrase---他
 |--Verb Phrase---英语讲
               |--Noun---英语
               |--Verb---讲
 |--Prepositional Phrase---得很好
                    |--Preposition---得
                    |--Complement---很好
                                 |--Adverb---很
                                 |--Adjective---好`

Notice that this sentence has a SOV structure and there is a prepositional phrase that explain the relationship between the verb and object.
In most cases mandarin follows a SVO structure so here it's an inversion.
This inversion is quite common.